# To add sub-menus to Menu button in android

Tags: android

I want to add action on clicking the Menu button on Android device. Suppose user is seeing Graph (one activity) now and he wants to switch to Charts. When user clicks the Menu button it has to show submenu say "Chart" this will be another activity. and then the user will switch to Charts.
How i can accomplish with this? can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 0):

override onMenuItemClicked function and call startActivity()

to add Menu item to an activity you need to override

onCreateMenuItem function.

Comment: The developer site has great documentation on option and context menus. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html